# Every time I drop a database, I have to manually kill the spid or I get an error: Cannot drop database currently in use

Tags: sql-server

There's a common error called:

> 3702. Cannot drop database current database is in use

where you cannot drop a database because for some reason the session wasn't closed properly.

A lot of people answer to first run

```
sp_who2,
```

check which connection is still running and then use

```
kill [spid num]
```

and then it will work.

However, for some reason this only works for the current database, if I recreate the database and add tables, and then try dropping it again, I will get the error again.
For some reason my server is not closing the spid's automatically.

Apparently, something is fundamentally wrong with my SQL Server (I'm using SQL Server).
Note that this only started happening after I installed SSMS.

Someone please help.
Thank you

Comment: SSMS usually opens a new connection to read in the metadata like tables and other objects, this might be a reason it has a connection open

Comment: @siggemannen Is there a way to stop SSMS from doing that?

Comment: Not sure, you could turn off Intellisence perhaps, but how often are you dropping databases? Perhaps you can write a procedure that kill spids against a specific db, sets single user and drops database

Comment: I’m learning sql, so I drop databases all the time.

Comment: Yeah, well, the next lesson is that you don't have to drop database in 99% of cases. Just create a new table etc.

Answer (score 1):

The following will drop the database by altering the database to set to a single user, as well as using the master

```
-- Drop the database 'DatabaseName'
-- Connect to the 'master' database to run this snippet
USE master
GO
-- Uncomment the ALTER DATABASE statement below to set the database to SINGLE_USER mode if the drop database command fails because the database is in use.
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
-- Drop the database if it exists
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT [name]
        FROM sys.databases
        WHERE [name] = N'DatabaseName'
)
DROP DATABASE DatabaseName
GO
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to fix the underlying problem, the regular drop database used to work just fine.

Comment: This will solve your problem of being unable to drop the database. SSMS will retain users.

Comment: I was about to suggest `ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`. Not sure if there is any advantage of one over the other.
`